# What are the equivalent variables for ReactDOM and document.body in React Native? (Expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm building a `Modal` component based on which I used for ReactJS on the web. I attach the `Modal` to `document.body` as a child and mount/unmount as needed.

Here is the diagram (Stephen Grider's Udemy online course)
[image]

**My problem is there is no ReactDOM or document.body in React Native.** Here is my modal.py

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { store } from '../store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
class Modal extends Component {
  comoponentDidMount() {
    this.modalTarget = document.createElement('div');
    this.modalTarget.className = 'modal';
    document.body.appendChild(this.modalTarget);
    this._render();
  }

  _render() {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      </Provider>,
      this.modalTarget
    );
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    this._render();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.modalTarget);
    document.body.removeChild(this.modalTarget);
  }

  render() {
    return <noscript />;
  }
}
```

**I'm using Expo and it's loading App.js by default! And there is no document.body and ReactDOM**. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have any DOM in react-native. you should create a modal component and import it in other components you want to use. your modal's position must be absolute and for showing modal you can pass a prop to it.

you can use react native modal:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html
or any other modals created by people like this :
https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox

Comment: I didn't want modal to get positioned by CSS from the screen. I have to deal with z-index to pop up the modal. My approach is to make a child of body so it solves CSS issue. Also fake modal on the component call the modal which is attached to the body.

Comment: Thanks for answering though. Thanks for putting your time on my problem