# How to access Tree Structure in React Native like React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I achieve those types of executions which have mentioned in React part?

An example in React:

```
<div onClick={(event)=>{}} style={{height: 500}}>
    <div style={{height: 300}}>
        <button onClick={(event)=>{}} style={{color: blue}}>Clickable</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the above example,

when onClick event of first div fires, I can execute:

- `event.currentTarget.children` -- to get all direct child elements
- `event.currentTarget.children[0].firstElementChild` - to get the button element
- `getComputedStyle(event.currentTarget).getPropertyValue('height')` -- to get computed height of the div

etc...

when onClick event of the button fires, I can execute:

- `event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement` --- to get the first div element
- `getComputedStyle(event.currentTarget).getPropertyValue('color')` -- to get computed color of the button

etc...

An example in React Native:

```
<Pressable onPress={()=>{}} style={{height: 500}}>
    <View style={{height: 300}}>
        <Button onPress={()=>{}} title="Clickable" color='blue' />
    </View>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: React native [does not have a DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741808/954986), that's browser specific. It doesn't handle click events and targets and stuff the same way. When running in the browser, it would of course, but I don't know how it maps to that. (I don't know too much about this topic, so it's possible I'm wrong)

Comment: @Nathan Here, I am meaning DOM like Tree Structure.