# How to know which button was clicked, in React Native?

Tags: react-native

First, I am from Web World(ReactJS), so not familier in React Native.

**How to know which button was clicked?**

Example:

```
const [titleOne, setTitleOne] = useState('A button 1');
const [titleTwo, setTitleTwo] = useState('A button 2');

const handlePress=(event)=>{
    /*
        if first button clicked,
        I want to write: setTitleOne(Button 1 clicked);
        
        if second button clicked,
        I want to write: setTitleTwo(Button 2 clicked);
    */
}

<View>
  <Button title={titleOne} onPress={handlePress} />
  <Button title={titleTwo} onPress={handlePress} />
</View>
```

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: can't we send an extra arg, as `onPress={(e)=>handlePress(e,"one")}` and then check inside the `handlePress` as `const handlePress = (event, btnName)` and couple of if's ?

Comment: @KcH please show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing an extra arg say `name` ...

```
const [titleOne, setTitleOne] = useState('A button 1');
const [titleTwo, setTitleTwo] = useState('A button 2');

const handlePress=(event, btnName)=>{
    if(btnName === "one"){
       setTitleOne("Button 1 clicked");
    }
    if(btnName === "two"){
       setTitleTwo("Button 2 clicked");
    }
}

<View>
  <Button title={titleOne} onPress={(e)=>handlePress(e,"one")} />
  <Button title={titleTwo} onPress={(e)=>handlePress(e,"two")} />
</View>
```

Comment: Thans a lot brother. Can you please answer another question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075763/how-to-access-tree-structure-in-react-native-like-react)

Comment: sorry, I have no idea 

Comment: Okay. So, we can not get applied styles of an element and also props, in react native, right?

Comment: There could be a different style, I'm not a RN dev or have idea tbh

Comment: Okay, thanks. just for curiosity, which technology you used to develop mobile apps?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const App = () => {

    const [titleOne, setTitleOne] = useState('A button 1');
    const [titleTwo, setTitleTwo] = useState('A button 2');

    const handlePress = (event) => {
        if (event == 1) {
            setTitleOne("Button 1 clicked")
        } else {
            setTitleTwo("Button 2 clicked")
        }
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title={"titleOne"} onPress={() => handlePress(1)} />
            <Button title={"titleTwo"} onPress={() => handlePress(2)} />
        </View>

    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot. (I do not know how to accept multiple answers; I tried)

Comment: Can you please answer another question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075763/how-to-access-tree-structure-in-react-native-like-react)